# output of scipy.io.wavfile.read() is always zero

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

Here is my code:

```
import scipy.io.wavfile
rate,data=scipy.io.wavfile.read('filename.wav')
```

I want to manipulate with data but the output of data is always zero. I used different `wav` files and again the output is zero. How can I fix it? I am working on Linux ubuntu and I use python2.7

Comment: Can you check with audacity or a similar software if your wav files are not flat (only 0) or 24bit ?
the function documentation says "This function cannot read wav files with 24 bit data"

Comment: In the python, it says;  dtype = int16

Comment: I'm not a master of wav reading, but maybe it's setting the dtype to int16 by default because it cannot read the file if it's 24bits. 
You can have the encoding information in a sound manipulator software like audacity.

Comment: I checked it but it is not 24bits.

Comment: I think we'll need access to one of the files.  Can you post one somewhere?

Comment: I have tried different wav files and it worked. I think the problem is because of the wav files.